# Why is date variable changing when adding days?

Tags: datetime, zend-framework

I want to display 2 dates: today and add 7 days so I have:

```
$date1 = new Zend_Date();  //assume today is 01/02/2014
$date2 = new Zend_Date($date1->add(7, Zend_Date::DAY)); 

print $date1 . ' to ' . $date2;
```

I would expect to see (ignoring the dateformat for now):
01/02/2014 to 08/02/2014

but I get:
08/02/2014 to 08/02/2014

Why is it that $date1 changes with $date2 and how to get a second date derived from a first date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zend_Date's `add` is a mutating operation, that is, `add` changes the original date instead of just returning a new `Date` with the offset added.

What you can do is to simply create a copy of the original `Date` and add to that;

```
$date1 = new Zend_Date();  //assume today is 01/02/2014
$date2 = new Zend_Date($date1);
$date2->add(7, Zend_Date::DAY);
```

Comment: Thanks. Feels like unnecessary work to first copy and then add in stead of calculating a date straight from the source. Anyway this works.